# Black Lines on top and bottom in Eevee render engine

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

I recently have tried to render an animation but every time I render there are black lines on the top and bottom that might be coming from the camera, I'm not sure. Please help

[image: black lines on top and bottom sample image]

Comment: hello, it's hard to guess, maybe an object that is hidden in preview in the Outliner?

Comment: I don't think there are any objects that are hidden

Comment: Do you want the whole file?

Comment: just leave some objects, make sure that the problems is still here, and share

Comment: Ok, I'll do that and let you know

Comment: It might take a while though

Comment: @iwantasandwichyt It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/wG0JJ7XQ

Comment: here is the file i am using. while you are at it, could you find out why my render has really bad quality and losing color? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two black lines are appearing because you add them via compositing here via alpha over:

[image]

and for better render quality:

maybe wanna change to cycles engine, add an hdri for lighting, then i changed render settings to this:

[image]

I checked denoise and set noise threshold to 0.1

result:

[image]

Comment: How do I get rid of the black lines then, is the compositing supposed to be in the animation?